# How can I make a Puppet module that fixes time?

Tags: ntp, puppet

I have written a Puppet module that corrects the time via NTP, but this only works on server with a small NTP offset.

There are sometimes server with a time offset higher than 10 minutes for various reasons.

I want to make a Puppet module that runs exec "service ntpd stop; ntpdate ntp3.domain.local; service ntpd start" when the ntp offset is too high, to forcably correct the time.

How can I see if the NTP offset is too high in order to tell Puppet to run this command? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: if you are running `ntpd`, why do you get such big time drifts? `ntpd` should be continually adjusting the time to *always* match. be aware that large time jumps can raise unexpected behaviour of loads of programs.

Comment: Check out that Q, they discuss the iburst feature of NTP which will force ntpd to "catchup" if the time is lagging far behind.

Comment: @slm: iburst will do no such thing. You want `-g` (or a tinker line)...

Comment: @derobert - That was the take away in that other thread. I've never tried it, I always use a ntpdate, it's just easier to me.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> service ntpd stop; ntpdate ntp3.domain.local; service ntpd start
> ```

is definitely the wrong solution for this problem. Use the `-g` option for `ntpd`:

```
   -g     Normally, ntpd exits with a message to the  system  log  if  the
          offset  exceeds the panic threshold, which is 1000 s by default.
          This option allows the time to  be  set  to  any  value  without
          restriction; however, this can happen only once.  If the thresh‐
          old is exceeded after that, ntpd will exit with a message to the
          system log.  This option can be used with the -q and -x options.
```

Combine this with the `iburst` option as slm suggested because without this it would take `ntpd` ages to correct such a huge difference. It usually tries to change the system time only in very small steps so that time-dependent applications don't get confused, but the `iburst` option will change this.

You will still have to ensure that Puppet automatically restarts `ntpd` after it panics, because according to the manpage it will fix the time once and then it will die nonetheless.

Comment: `iburst` ONLY causes ntpd to initially send more packets. It makes the initial decision of "what time is it, really?" take ~10s instead of ~5m. Unless you've used `-x` (or some `tinker` options), a time offset >128ms will always be stepped, i.e., instant.